# AWS IAM: List the resources a role has accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless

I am currently working on a serverless project that has two aws lambda functions which are accessing some aws ressources. My current role statements are pretty open

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - iot:*
        - sts:*
        - ssm:*
      Resource:
        - '*'
```

Now I want to strengthen the policy and just give the functions the authorizations they actually need. Is there a way to see which actions on resources the dynamically created role has been used? 
With that information I could create a more fine grained policy. Currently I am using "trail and error" which is not very effective.

Thanks for your feedback,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to give each lambda it's own IAM role, thereby you're able to more tightly manage the permission on each lambda uniquely. Some frameworks like serverless have plugins that allow you to do just this.

Once you've set the IAM roles per lambda -- head on over to AWS Cloudtrail. It'll give you the recent events that your lambda executed -- and you can easily see what the lambda was doing and tighten it back.

Of course, it's far better to review the actual code of your function, but this is probably a good-ish compromise if you don't have code available for whatever reason.